# How can i create a process tree using fork()?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I have to create a tree with 3 nodes and each of this 3 nodes, also have 3 nodes.
I was able to do a root node with 3 children and dont know how to create  3 children nodes from newly created children from root:
Below is my pseudocode:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

            exit(0);
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Should i just use another loop inside if condition but it creates a mess. TIA!

Comment: That's not real C code. Please show the actual valid C code that you have tested.

Comment: edited the code !

Comment: The code does not exactly _create 3 children_.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `pstree` command.

Run 2 shells: on the first shell use the command ps to get your shell process PID, then run the code. On the other shell, run `pstree -p <pid>`

Here is an quick example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("%d &\n", getpid());
        }
  }
  sleep(20);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output after running pstree command:
[image]